# SQL select where ALL records of id = 'x' have status of 'y'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a single table `incoming` which contains a list of emails , and their attachments.

I import each of the attachements, and process them, at which point that row gets marked as `5`

When all rows of an individual email are marked as 5, I can then move/delete the email as it has been processed correctly.

However, I'm struggling to write a SQL query which is to select the `msg_uid` where ALL rows with the same `msg_uid` have a status of `5`

Example table

```
 -----------------------------------------------------
 | id | STATUS | i2d_id | msg_uid | i2d_msg          |
 -----------------------------------------------------
 | 16 | 5      | 98390  | 53      | Result is ready. |
 -----------------------------------------------------
 | 17 | 3      | 98391  | 53      | Result is ready. |
 -----------------------------------------------------
 | 18 | 5      | 98392  | 53      | Result is ready. |
 -----------------------------------------------------
 | 19 | 3      | 98393  | 53      | Result is ready. |
 -----------------------------------------------------
 | 20 | 5      | 98394  | 53      | Result is ready. |
 -----------------------------------------------------
```

This would not allow me to remove the email (some have status `3`

But

```
-----------------------------------------------------
| id | STATUS | i2d_id | msg_uid | i2d_msg          |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 16 | 5      | 98390  | 53      | Result is ready. |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 17 | 5      | 98391  | 53      | Result is ready. |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 18 | 5      | 98392  | 53      | Result is ready. |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 19 | 5      | 98393  | 53      | Result is ready. |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 20 | 5      | 98394  | 53      | Result is ready. |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Would be a success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 SELECT msg_uid 
 FROM yourTable
 GROUP BY msg_uid 
 HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 5 THEN 1 END)
```

Comment: I've given this one as the answer as although @Lamak answer works as well, I feel this one is more readable (slightly easier for me to understand)

Answer (score 2):

This query will let yoy find every result where all of the `STATUS` values are `5` for a particular `msg_uid`:

```
SELECT *
FROM incoming i
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM incoming
                 WHERE msg_uid = i.msg_uid
                 AND `status` <> 5);
```

Comment: Probably `SELECT DISTINCT msg_uid` is more appropiate for OP request.

Comment: I interpreted the question as asking for every row. But if op needs every different `msg_uid` and nothing else, then yes, `SELECT DISTINCT msg_uid` would be the way to do it

Comment: @Lamak - thanks for the answer - it works, but I feel I can understand the other answer a bit more :)